# Conflicting constant lookup in rspec (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

On our project, we have the following:

```
module A
 # several components belong to this namespace
end

module Databuilder::A
 # several components also belong to this namespace
#
```

When running the full test suite, in which one of the tests is like this:

```
describe ::A::AnotherNamespace::MyService do
# code ommited
```

The following error shows up:

```
uninitialized constant DataBuilder::A::AnotherNamespace
```

Unfortunately, renaming the namespace A is not an option because the components belong to a legacy monolith.

Manually requiring the file which contains `:A::AnotherNamespace::MyService` leads to the same error.

The files on `DataBuilder::` ... live inside the /lib folder. The ones from the `A` namespace live inside a app/"a" folder

I'm running rspec-rails 4.0.0 / rails 5.2.4 in a ruby 2.3.0 rbenv.
No customization has been done to the autoloading.

Comment: Check your stacktrace. I have a suspicion that the describe line is not what is causing your issue. `A` is properly namespaced as `::A` there, so it should work fine. Is there maybe another `A` somewhere in your code that is not properly (::) namespaced?

Comment: The stack trace has only one line, pointing exactly to the `describe` line. All points of my code point to ::A

Comment: Moving the spec files from spec/"a" to spec/app/"a" gets rid of the error when running the full suite.

However I'm still interested in knowing why this happens, as the convention would be to put the files directly inside the /spec folder, like spec/controllers, spec/models, etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a sample app? Just the act of trying to do that might shed light on what's wrong.